# Role 'DBT_DEV_ROLE' specified in the connect string does not exist or not authorized

Tags: database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, etl, data-warehouse, dbt

I am following this tutorial: https://quickstarts.snowflake.com/guide/data_engineering_with_dbt/#1

I ran this in my worksheet after selecting the securityadmin role and then sysadmin role,

```
-------------------------------------------
-- dbt credentials
-------------------------------------------
USE ROLE securityadmin;
-- dbt roles
CREATE OR REPLACE ROLE dbt_dev_role;
CREATE OR REPLACE ROLE dbt_prod_role;
------------------------------------------- Please replace with your dbt user password
CREATE OR REPLACE USER dbt_user PASSWORD = "<mysecretpassword>";

GRANT ROLE dbt_dev_role,dbt_prod_role TO USER dbt_user;
GRANT ROLE dbt_dev_role,dbt_prod_role TO ROLE sysadmin;

-------------------------------------------
-- dbt objects
-------------------------------------------
USE ROLE sysadmin;

CREATE OR REPLACE WAREHOUSE dbt_dev_wh  WITH WAREHOUSE_SIZE = 'XSMALL' AUTO_SUSPEND = 60 AUTO_RESUME = TRUE MIN_CLUSTER_COUNT = 1 MAX_CLUSTER_COUNT = 1 INITIALLY_SUSPENDED = TRUE;
CREATE OR REPLACE WAREHOUSE dbt_dev_heavy_wh  WITH WAREHOUSE_SIZE = 'LARGE' AUTO_SUSPEND = 60 AUTO_RESUME = TRUE MIN_CLUSTER_COUNT = 1 MAX_CLUSTER_COUNT = 1 INITIALLY_SUSPENDED = TRUE;
CREATE OR REPLACE WAREHOUSE dbt_prod_wh WITH WAREHOUSE_SIZE = 'XSMALL' AUTO_SUSPEND = 60 AUTO_RESUME = TRUE MIN_CLUSTER_COUNT = 1 MAX_CLUSTER_COUNT = 1 INITIALLY_SUSPENDED = TRUE;
CREATE OR REPLACE WAREHOUSE dbt_prod_heavy_wh  WITH WAREHOUSE_SIZE = 'LARGE' AUTO_SUSPEND = 60 AUTO_RESUME = TRUE MIN_CLUSTER_COUNT = 1 MAX_CLUSTER_COUNT = 1 INITIALLY_SUSPENDED = TRUE;

GRANT ALL ON WAREHOUSE dbt_dev_wh  TO ROLE dbt_dev_role;
GRANT ALL ON WAREHOUSE dbt_dev_heavy_wh  TO ROLE dbt_dev_role;
GRANT ALL ON WAREHOUSE dbt_prod_wh TO ROLE dbt_prod_role;
GRANT ALL ON WAREHOUSE dbt_prod_heavy_wh  TO ROLE dbt_prod_role;

CREATE OR REPLACE DATABASE dbt_hol_dev; 
CREATE OR REPLACE DATABASE dbt_hol_prod; 
GRANT ALL ON DATABASE dbt_hol_dev  TO ROLE dbt_dev_role;
GRANT ALL ON DATABASE dbt_hol_prod TO ROLE dbt_prod_role;
GRANT ALL ON ALL SCHEMAS IN DATABASE dbt_hol_dev   TO ROLE dbt_dev_role;
GRANT ALL ON ALL SCHEMAS IN DATABASE dbt_hol_prod  TO ROLE dbt_prod_role;
```

I have this in my profiles.yml file:

```
dbt_hol:
  target: dev
  outputs:
    dev:
      type: snowflake
      ######## Please replace with your Snowflake account name
      account: xyz.eu-central-1

      user: TEST
      ######## Please replace with your Snowflake dbt user password
      password: password

 role: dbt_dev_role
      database: dbt_hol_dev
      warehouse: dbt_dev_wh
      schema: public
      threads: 200
    prod:
      type: snowflake
      ######## Please replace with your Snowflake account name
      account: xyz.eu-central-1

      user: TEST
      ######## Please replace with your Snowflake dbt user password
      password: password

      role: dbt_prod_role
      database: dbt_hol_prod
      warehouse: dbt_prod_wh
      schema: public
threads: 200
```

Although I am following the tutorial, when I run `dbt debug`, I get an error that:

```
Connection:
  account: xyz.eu-central-1
  user: TEST
  database: dbt_hol_dev
  schema: public
  warehouse: dbt_dev_wh
  role: dbt_dev_role
  client_session_keep_alive: False
  Connection test: ERROR

dbt was unable to connect to the specified database.
The database returned the following error:

  >Database Error
  250001 (08001): Failed to connect to DB: xyz.eu-central-1.snowflakecomputing.com:443. Role 'DBT_DEV_ROLE' specified in the connect string does not exist or not authorized. Contact your local system administrator, or attempt to login with another role, e.g. PUBLIC.
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see, you try to connect using the user TEST:

```
Connection:
  account: xyz.eu-central-1
  user: TEST
  database: dbt_hol_dev
  schema: public
  warehouse: dbt_dev_wh
  role: dbt_dev_role
  client_session_keep_alive: False
  Connection test: ERROR
```

On the other hand, you granted the dbt_dev_role to the following users:

```
GRANT ROLE dbt_dev_role,dbt_prod_role TO USER dbt_user;
GRANT ROLE dbt_dev_role,dbt_prod_role TO ROLE sysadmin;
```

You need to grant the role to the user TEST.